# Document Library thumbnail field is missing when added to a publishing page

Tags: sharepoint-online, image-display, thumbnail

I've created a document library with image files in it and a columns of type Picture and column name = Thumbnail. When in the document library itself, this column auto-generates a thumbnail of the image. However, when I load the library into a publishing page, the thumbnail does not load on the page. It's not hidden or styled out - it doesn't even show in the DOM tree as having loaded an image. It's just a blank .

[image]
I'm not sure what's going on or how to get it to load the thumb. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a classic page or a modern page?

If it is a classic page, by default the library web part would not load the thumbnail column. Try to edit the web part to select a view that contains this thumb column.

[image]

Comment: This is a classic publishing page - not the modern experience. 
The thumbnail column is in the view. I've even tried moving its position left/right. It's the same view that shows in the library page directly. The <td></td> simply shows nothing when then library web part is inserted onto the page. It's the strangest thing.